# no functional relationship between ρ and φ

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Consider an arbitrary, continuously differentiable function of two variables, $V(x,y)$, and the coordinate substitution $x=\rho\cos\phi$, $y=\rho\sin\phi$.
Prove that there is no functional relationship between $\rho$ and $\phi$; that is, there is no function g such that $g(\rho,\phi)=0$ for all $\rho$ and $\phi$.

My clue is:
We know $\rho=x^2+y^2$ and $\tan\phi=\frac{y}{x}$
Assume there exists g such that $g(\rho,\phi)=0$, and prove it is conflict with something else.
Can anyone help me the rest? Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify how $V$ enters the question? As written, the constant function $g = 0$ provides a trivial answer.

Comment: @Neal Oh there is a second question which is related to V. But I can solve that one. Just the first question I have no clue.

Comment: @YibeiHe: what Neal means is that there us no trace of $x $, $y $, nor $V $ in the question. By definition,  the only function that is zero on all $(\rho,\phi) $ is $g=0$.